# Get properties from array of objects group by objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, object

Good day, I have an array `artists[]` of Proxy-objects. Proxy by themself also are arrays of objects (as I understood). Each of inner objects has property `"artistName"` (photo). Meanwhile third Proxy has two.

[image]

I need to get smth like this:

```
[
  ["Queen"],
  ["Pink Floyd"],
  ["Elvis Presley", "Pink Floyd"],
]
```

So, as result we get arrays of artist's names grouped by Proxy objects. Please, help!

Comment: Post the original array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two levels of arrays, so you'll need two loops (or map functions).  Give this a try

```
const names = artists.map(grp => grp.map(band => band.artistName))
```